# Drawing around an image to get the X/Y coordinates with jQuery. Like image maps in Dreamweaver

Tags: javascript, jquery, image

Is there a way of drawing around an image and getting the coordinates like image maps in Dreamweaver.

I would then like to use the coordinates so that the user can get information about an image depending on what part of the image they have clicked on. Like http://store.nike.com/us/en_us/product/free-flash-id/builder/

The problem is that I don't know how to get the coordinates. I want to be able to trace around an image and get the coordinates. Then use the coordinates in a function. When a user clicks inside the coordinates the js will say "you just clicked on this area of the image"

Thanks!

Comment: Yes, they exist. What's the problem here, exactly? After asking 30 questions you should know how to write a half decent one

Comment: whats wrong with using image maps? why do you need to reinvent it?

Answer (score 1):

You can get the coordinates of a user click inside an image (relative to the image) like this (fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/j8DBw/) :

```
var imageCoords = $("img").offset();

$("img").click(function(event){
    var clickPageCoords = {
        x:event.clientX,
        y:event.clientY
    }

    var imageRelativeCoords = {
        x: clickPageCoords.x - imageCoords.left,
        y: clickPageCoords.y - imageCoords.top,
    }
    console.log(imageRelativeCoords);
})
```

Comment: Thanks Pax, the jsfiddle does not work for me but I like the idea, I think that would work well.

Comment: I'm just getting this error ""NetworkError: 500 Internal Server Error - http://jobs.jsfiddle.net/random.js?callback=Request.JSONP.request_map.request_0"" I think I will use the links below but thanks for your solution.

Comment: @user2238083 Well, if you click on the image, some coords should show up.

Comment: Yes sorry I had it on the "error" setting in console should have been  set to "All". Thanks, works great!

Comment: @user2238083 No problem, glad to be of assistance. Don't forget to accept/upvote the answer if it was useful.

Answer (score 0):

I thought image maps was only a Dreamweaver feature. After VeXii's comment I found these solutions.

http://www.maschek.hu/imagemap/

http://www.image-maps.com/

Thanks for everyones help!